# Getting marginal density from joint density function

Tags: probability, random-variables

If the joint frequency function of random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\alpha \beta e^{-\alpha x-\beta y}$ $\,\,\,\,x\geq 0$ $\,\,\,\,y\geq 0$

then to get, for example, the marginal density function of $Y$ we would integrate the joint frequency function with respect to $X$.

This would give $f_Y(y)=\beta e^{-\beta y}$.

What I'm not totally clear on is how you would use this. I understand the discrete case, where if you want the marginal density of $Y=2$, you sum the row or column of $Y=2$ across all the $X$ values.

Here, how would you get the marginal probability that $Y$ takes on a value in a certain interval? It seems like you should integrate but what would the bounds be? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $P(Y=y)=0$ for any real number $y$ (in particular $y=2$).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, absolutely, just edited. So you integrate over your desired bounds, is that right?

Comment: @fmtcs sorry I don't exactly understand your question

Comment: @fmtcs : there was also a typo in your $f_Y(y)$. Amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(c<Y<d)=\int_c^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy$

Answer (score 1):

the given density can be rewritten in the following way

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\alpha e^{-\alpha x}\times \beta e^{-\beta x}=f_X(x)\times f_Y(y)$$

thus you immediately get your marginals as independent exponentials

Answer (score 0):

The marginal density is defined as $$f_Y(y) = \int f(x, y) dx$$. In this case, you treat $y$ as a constant, giving you $$\int_0^\infty \alpha \beta e^{-\alpha x - \beta y} dx = \beta e^{-\beta y} \int_0^\infty \alpha e^{-\alpha x} dx = \beta e^{-\beta y}$$

Comment: Yes, I already did that in my question. I'm trying to draw similarities to the discrete case where to actually go from the marginal density to a probability you just sum the column or row of $Y$ across all $X$ values.

Comment: In the discrete case, you replace the integral symbol with a summation symbol. And you use $f_Y$ as you would any PDF, just integrate it to get the probability of Y lying in a certain intervals.